# kernel density estimation in qgis plugin?

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I have tried using animove plugin, but it keeps coming up with errors, is there a way to do a kernal density estimation for 50% and 95% in qgis for point data?

Comment: Menu processing > Toolbox > Heatmap (Kernel Density Estimation)

Comment: How do you set up this tool and interpret the parameters?

Comment: As this is another question, you should open a separate post for it

Comment: Did you try to look in the QGIS documentation? This is always the first step: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/interpolation.html#heatmap-kernel-density-estimation